# Periodic Solution in a Non-Homogeneous Linear System of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've encountered the following question, and I'm not sure how to approach:

> Let $A\in M_{n}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ a matrix that has only negative real-part eigenvalues, and let $f:\mathbb{R\to R}^{n}$ be some function. Prove that for all $t_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$ the equation $x^{\prime}\left(t\right)=Ax\left(t\right)+f\left(t\right)$ has at most one solution s.t. $x\left(t\right)=x\left(t+t_{0}\right)$ for every $t$.

I've tried to assume that there're two solutions like that and taking $t\to\infty$, but I'd like to get a hint, because I can't figure this out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If $x_1, x_2$ are two solutions, then:

1. $y=x_2-x_1$ is a solution of the equation $y^\prime(t) = Ay(t)$. As $A$ has only negative real part eigenvalues, $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} y(t)=0$.
2. Derive a contradiction if it exists $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $y(a) \neq 0$ using the periodicity hypothesis.